# rails number_to_human for negative numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am passing a negative number to number_to_human() method in rails and I am getting 0 in return. Is it the right behavior ? I couldn't seem to find an example for number_to_human with a negative number as argument.

Comment: Ahh just realized, Its my mistake. number_to_human() also accepts negative numbers and prints them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake. number_to_human() accepts negative numbers too and prints the right value.